# Воспроизведения коротких звуков с повторением на движке AndEngine

Tags: мобильная-разработка, android, аудио, andengine, java

Добрый день.

Делаю игру. Нужно добавить звук выстрела из лазерной пушки (моей + n врагов).

Пробовал и `org.andengine.audio.music.Music;` и `org.andengine.audio.sound.Sound;`.

Оба через `play()` включаются один раз, и если вызывать еще раз до того, как закончится проигрывание, новый звук не появляется!

Как сделать наложение одного и того же звука?

Answer (score 1):

Если приемлемо использование сторонней библиотеки, то, может, стоит попробовать пускать звук через [Jlayer](http://www.javazoom.net/projects.html). Ресурсов затрачивает мало, имеет поддержку разных форматов, работать с ней довольно просто. Часто натыкался на использование данной библиотеки в android проектах. На своем опыте могу сказать, что тут нет проблем с наложением звуковых эффектов друг на друга.

Если неприемлемо: на [этом](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/play-2-sounds-at-same-time-t1493.html) форуме у человека схожая проблема, посмотрите на второй странице, там предлагают два разных решения, одно - с настройками, другое - с менеджером.

Comment: Зачем тянуть всю либу Jlayer, если в андроиде уже предусмотрено решение?  
@Захар Золотарёв, [android.media.SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)  Я бы рекомендовал все звуки сжать в ogg - с ними работа лучше, чем с mp3.